# Xcode freezes at indexing, randomly, iPhone dev

Tags: xcode

My Xcode version is 4.6.2, which is the latest at this moment 2013.6.2, when I try to run a project(not a specified one) in simulator, it randomly freezes(stops) at indexing. I don't know if it's my macbook's problem because it's relatively a old one. My project is very light-weighted, just some demo. I'm a newbie. Normally, it works well, but sometimes it freezes at indexing, say 5% possibility.

And I cannot stop it even I clicked the "Stop" button at the right of "Run", and either if I close the simulator. I have to force the computer to shut down by keep pressing the power button. It brings damage to computer.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Or I have to get a newer one? Any help will be appreciated. THANKS.

Screenshot:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have only 2gb of memory in your laptop. It maybe not enough to run the program while your other programs are running. You may need to just to upgrade your memory which is not that expensive. Just add another 2gb and see if your machine runs faster and the xcode can compile faster. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Xcode 4.6.2 in 1.4GHz, 2GB Ram

This is the main problem, the Xcode needs 2GB+ itself, and there are others applications and processes running in foreground and background.

I have 3GHz C2D, 4GB RAM, still at times it hangs at times :(

So, either you need to upgrade the hardware or degrade the Xcode version.

**EDIT:**

*As you have Macbook air, you cant upgrade the RAM which is soldered to the motherboard.*

Comment: Hi Anoop, thanks, is it possible to upgrade the memory for macbook air? BTW, I just learned that command+right click on dock could force the application to close, no need to force shut down anymore lolz

Comment: @JimZ: Also alt+hold left click.

Comment: NO...you cant upgrade the ram.

Comment: Disappointed to know, I guess I should upgrad to a latest one after I make some money from my App haha, say one million dollars huh?

Comment: you can buy a monitor at $100 and a tiffin box.